# How To Enable CodeLens in Visual Studio 2017 Mac Professional

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I have recently upgraded to the Professional edition of Visual Studio for Mac 2017. I want to enable the Code Lens feature, but don't see any option to do so in Preferences.

I have performed several searches on Stack Overflow, Microsoft's Visual Studio support sites, and Google. Most results are users asking how to enable codelens in the Community edition of Visual Studio 2017.

How do I actually enable codelens in Visual Studio Professional 2017 for Mac?

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio for Mac doesn't have CodeLens; it's not a direct port of Visual Studio, but rather a rebranded and expanded version of Xamarin Studio.